# Lagging ScrollLeft Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a horizontal scroll page with 30+ images. When scrolling the page show some lagging on the scroll animation. Any alternative for the scroll left function?

Javascript:

```
$('.arrow').click(function(){
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('body, html').animate({
                        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href') ).offset().left},500);
                        return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this without return false;

```
$('.arrow').click(function(){
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('body, html').animate({
                        scrollLeft: $(this).offset().width}, 500,          
                        function(){
                            // do something after animation complete.
                         }

    });
```